# Find the power of 2

Tags: algorithms

Assume $n=2^k$, write an algorithm that can find $k$.

**log function is not allowed.

Is there an efficient way to find the power instead of multiplying by 2 until it equals $n$? What is the optimal efficiency?

Comment: Compute $1,2,4,8,16,\ldots$ until you exceed $n$.

Comment: I’d allow the log function (which is base 10 or base e usually, depending on the language used), giving zero points if the answer is not correct in all cases. And not “assume n = 2^k” but ”verify that N = 2^k”. First test case would be n = 2^63-1.

Comment: It depends on the input range, whether it is bounded. And can k be negative?

Comment: And it can depend on implementation. If we assume a binary computer, finding k is finding first 1 in the binary, or, with standard floating point numbers, just picking the exponent field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming arithmetic operations take constant time, you can compute it in $O(\log \log n)$ time.

Start with $n_0=2$ and iteratively compute $n_i  = n_{i-1} \cdot n_{i-1} = 2^{2^i}$ until $n_{i} > n$.

The number of iterations is then $\log \log n$ and $ n_{i-1} = 2^{2^{i-1}}  \le n < 2^{2^i} = n_i$.
At this point you can binary search for the right exponent among the $2^i - 2^{i-1} = 2^{i-1} \le k$ possible exponents. This takes time $O(\log k) = O(\log \log n)$ (exponentiation with a base of $2$ can usually be performed with a single left shift operation).